Antenna amplifier circuit design
I am trying to build a Simple NMR spectrometer. The idea is to excite a sample sustained in a magnetic field with a high wattage RF impulse around 20~30 MHz and then detect the echo (respond signal emitted by the sample). I plan to detect this signal with a coil ( antenna), amplify it and send to an osciloscope. The problem is how can I make/design proper amplifier circuit for such small (microvolt,low voltage) signal. It probably should be low noise amplifier. I have OPA 2658 amplifier, maybe it will be useful?

There's a book I have on the shelf (and have read) called, "150 and More Basic NMR Experiments: A Practical Course", and in my case it is the 2nd Completely Revised and Enlarged Edition by Siegmar Braun, Hans-Otto Kalinowski, & Stefan Berger. Are you already familiar with its material? If so, you should provide those relevant details here in your question. What you've written here is, in my opinion only, sufficiently incomplete that useful answers are improbable.
